# error while make in pythia 8186 using ROOT 5.34

Tags: c++, root-framework

I am compiling my own program in pythia 8186 with the following commands:

```
g++ `root-config --ldflags` -o mymain03 mymain03.cc `root-config --glibs`
```

I got following error :

```
mymain03.cc:4:28: fatal error: Pythia8/Pythia.h: No such file or directory
   #include "Pythia8/Pythia.h"
                        ^
```

compilation terminated.
and when I use the following command:

```
g++ -O2 -ansi -pedantic -W -Wall -Wshadow -I$PYTHIA8/include mymain03.cc -o mymain03
```

I got the following error:

```
mymain03.cc:5:19: fatal error: TTree.h: No such file or directory
 #include "TTree.h"
               ^
```

compilation terminated.

Comment: you need the pythia compile flags *and* the root link and *compile* flags at the same time. so combining your attempts and adding --cflags:  `g++ $(root-config --glibs) -o mymain03 mymain03.cc $(root-config --cflags) -O2 -ansi -pedantic -Wshadow -I$PYTHIA8/include`

Comment: i got so many errors now

Comment: mymain03.cc:(.text.startup+0x2bb): undefined reference to `Pythia8::Pythia::~Pythia()'
mymain03.cc:(.text.startup+0x31a): undefined reference to `Pythia8::Pythia::~Pythia()'
mymain03.cc:(.text.startup+0x33d): undefined reference to `TObject::operator delete(void*)'
/tmp/ccp3KEMk.o: In function `_GLOBAL__sub_I_main':
mymain03.cc:(.text.startup+0x3eb): undefined reference to `TVersionCheck::TVersionCheck(int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: good. you're from compiler errors to linker errors now. You're missing something that adds `-Lpath/to/where/pythia/is` and `-lpythialibrary1` `-lpythialibrary2` and so on for all the pythia libraries your program needs.